# Computing average delay by destination in flights

Tags: r

I am trying to solve a task that says: `Compute the average delay by destination, then join on the airports data frame so you can show the spatial distribution of delays. Here’s an easy way to draw a map of the United States`

So my initial approach is to compute the avarage delay. I am new to R, and so far I've not read about loops in the chapters, so I don't think that I'm supposed to use loops. I want to do it without, if possible. In any other programming language I'd do something like:

```
for i= 1 to flights.length
   for j = i to flights.length
         if flight[i].destination == flight[j].destination 
            avarage += (flight[i].arr_delay + flight[j].arr_delay)/i;
```

If it's helpful, here is the link to what I'm trying to solve: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/relational-data.html#exercises-30

I am kind of stuck. This is what I have in R so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(maps)
library(nycflights13)

fl <- flights %>% 
   filter(!is.na(arr_delay)) %>% 
     group_by(arr_delay)

view(mutate(fl, "avgDelay" = mean(arr_delay)))
```

The new column that is added, that I call "avgDelay" just shows the same values as arr_delay, so I'm definately doing it wrong.

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: Help ppl help you by providing reproducible data

Comment: The R code that I provided is reproducible. I'm not sure what other code to provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of reproducible data and given the lack of clarity of what your data look like and what your aims are, here's a wild shot at what you **could** mean.
The header to your post mentions "average delay by destinations". This suggests you have at least two variables, one we can call `delay`, one we will call `destination`. Here's a dataframe with some sampled data for illustration:

**DATA**:

```
set.seed(122)
delay <- sample(0:200, 10)
destination <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], 10, replace = T)
df <- data.frame(delay, destination)
df
   delay destination
1     57           C
2    157           B
3     81           C
4    174           B
5    185           A
6      8           C
7    102           A
8    173           A
9    106           A
10    87           C
```

**SOLUTION**:

To compute the average delay by destination you can use `tapply`and the function `mean`:

```
tapply(df$delay, df$destination, mean)
     A      B      C 
141.50 165.50  58.25
```

Does this get anywhere close to what you were after?